# coredns container stuck in containercreating state when trying to create a cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I'm trying to create a Kubernetes cluster on AWS. I've installed all the dependencies and done the kubeadm init.
kubeadm init --apiserver-advertise-address= --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
I even got the command to join the node to the cluster. 
I have two problems:
1. I get nodes in the notReady status when i do kubectl get nodes
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QiD57.png)
why is that so?
2. Two of my codedns pods are stuck in containercreating state
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9EhV.png)
 Why is this happening?

Comment: SUrely the containerCreating status is because there is no ready nodes. You should get kubelet logs from the nodes to see what's happening.

Comment: when I do kubectl describe pod <pod_name>, I get an error saying pod not found.

Comment: Is it because you are using unlicensed Windows :) as shown in the screen captures. Just kidding.

Comment: Hahah I wish that was the issue, could have been sorted easilt :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the screenshots attached, I assume that you didn't deploy any [CNI network](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) into your cluster; as a result, coredns Pods are in failed status.

I recommend installing one of the Pod network addons from the link above. In case of any re-occurred issue, try to bootstrap cluster from scratch. You can find a good article [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720380/kubernetes-api-server-is-not-starting-on-a-single-kubeadm-cluster) with detailed instruction for `kubeadm` installation procedure published by @VKR.

In case of any errors during the installation, post them below this answer.

Comment: Ohhh thanks!! I deployed calico CNI and it started working :)

Comment: Great! If you found that solution fixed you issue, kindly accept the answer, so the other contributors will know a way solving the similar problem.

Comment: I have a related question.. Are you willing to comment?  Here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55112356/are-these-pods-inside-the-overlay-network