# kube-apiserver multiple restarts

Tags: kubernetes

would like some help debugging this issue we are seeing. We are experiencing kube-api pods continually restarting over time exiting with code 0. We are seeing these restarts as frequent as multiple times in an hour. We are still able to connect to the api server to perform normal kubectl operations, the issue here is the high number of restarts, and the continual restarts over time for example : 471 restarts in 7 days. Our investigation has led us to check the liveness probe of the pod and switched from http to tcp with no effect. We’ve bumped the verbosity of the api logs up to 10 and we are able to see that a healthz check etcd fails multiple times in the log and are not certain thats directly related, but seeing as the last occurrence is so close to the pod shutdown it seems possible.

We've followed the etcd errors further, and to verify that this is indeed what is causing the restarts we have excluded the etcd from the healthz check ( https://gitlab.dev.cncf.ci/kubernetes/kubernetes/commit/69be3057de702e93c2bee84d00f24e932c36590f ) and are currently monitoring the apiserver.

Any additional thoughts on continual/high restart count for the apiserver?

Comment: Hi Ricardo, welcome to SO. If you "see that a healthz check etcd fails multiple times in the log" that is very, very, very, very bad, and is a good reason why the apiserver would _be_ restarted -- not so much that it, itself, exited but that it was terminated for failing its health check: you can read more here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#container-states

Comment: Hi Ricardo please provide more details about this issue by running:
`kubectl logs <your kube-apiserver pod> -n kube-system, 
journalctl -u kubelet,
kubectl get all --all-namespaces`.
Please follow also community answer related to kube-api server issues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52720380/kubernetes-api-server-is-not-starting-on-a-single-kubeadm-cluster/52724543#527245)
Please update your env (docker.io, kubelet, kubeadm, kubectl)
Share with the results and findings.

Comment: So via further investigation I believe I believe i've narrowed down the issue to the healthz check itself. So the etcd check is failing, but I don't see etcd connectivity issues when directly hitting etcd health endpoint from the master node. I do notice though that response times may take up to 2.6 seconds and may be too large for the check ie. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/apiserver/pkg/storage/storagebackend/factory/etcd3.go#L74

Comment: We were able to exclude the etcd check and no longer see restarts, and as we currently have various monitors around etcd itself, we may plan to stick with this configuration.

Comment: @Ricardo may I know how did you able to exclude etcd check in a problematic master node? Our production cluster is working fine except for the specific master node which always gets into Not Ready status due to the etcd health check. The kube-apiserver pod of that problematic master keeps retarting abnormally too